# Is This Conditional Probability Problem asking for Pr(A|B) or Pr(A and B)?

Tags: probability

A jar contains black and white marbles. Two marbles are chosen without replacement. The probability of selecting a black marble and then a white marble is 0.34, and the probability of selecting a black marble on the first draw is 0.47. What is the probability of selecting a white marble on the second draw, given that the first marble drawn was black? [the source](http://www.mathgoodies.com/lessons/vol6/conditional.html)

It is the English of this problem that causes me problems.

> The probability of selecting a black marble and then a white marble is 0.34

Shouldn't that be P(White | Black) not P(Black and White) because P(Black and White) = P(White and Black).  $P(B \cap W) = P(W \cap B)$  The reason I think this is because

> The probability of selecting a black marble and **then** a white marble is 0.34

The site says that means P(Black and White).   I would agree with that if **then** was removed from the sentence.

Conditional Probability word problems always confuse me because the wording is always non-standard.

Is there a standard grammatical syntax for conditional probability problems to distinguish  between P(A and B) and P(A | B).

I understand P(A and B) means that both events occur while P(A | B) means that given (knowing) event B occurred what is the probability that event A occurs(follows)

Comment: @GerryMyerson fixed that, that was my carelessness.  Do you have a comment about the problem above?

Comment: *Given* refers to $\mid$ while *And* refers to $\cap$. // Which textbook do you use?

Comment: @DidierPiau the problem for me is understanding when they mean **given** but don't use the exact word given and how to tell when and is just a conjunction of two clauses rather than the conjunction of two events.

Comment: 1. Some examples where neither *given* nor *conditional on* nor *knowing that* are used to mean $\mid\ $? 2. What is the difference between a conjunction of clauses and a conjunction of events? 3.Which textbook do you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The events labelled "Black" and "White" are really "first marble black" and "second marble white" (I think this is confusing: it would be better to label these as something like "B1" and "W2").  If they just said "a black marble and a white marble" it would also include the case of a white marble first and a black marble second.

Comment: thanks, I was confused as well by the wording of the problem.  Thanks for your clarification of the issue. It is a great help when English is not your native language to have someone help explain your problem more clearly.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There are four possible outcomes, $bb,bw,wb$, and $ww$. *The probability of selecting a black marble and then a white marble* is the probability of the outcome $bw$. Let $X$ represent the first draw and $Y$ the second; then symbolically this is $\Bbb{P}(X=b\land Y=w)$ (where $\land$ is ‘and’). The word *then* has to be there in order to distinguish the outcome $bw$ from the outcome $wb$: these are not the same outcome, since we’re keeping track of the order of the draws.

*The probability of selecting a black marble and a white marble* would be the probability of getting $bw$ **or** $wb$, which is larger than the probability of getting specifically $bw$, i.e., **first** a black and **then** a white marble.

Neither of these is a conditional probability: each is simply the probability of a certain outcome. On the other hand, *the probability of selecting a white marble on the second draw, given that the first marble drawn was black* **is** a conditional probability, $\Bbb{P}(Y=w\mid X=b)$. This is signalled by the words *given that*: *the probability of A given B* is $\Bbb{P}(A\mid B)$.

Once you’ve correctly interpreted the problem, the rest is straightforward, but I’ll include it for the sake of completeness. The basic formula

$$\Bbb{P}(X=b\land Y=w)=\Bbb{P}(X=b)\Bbb{P}(Y=w\mid X=b)$$

becomes $0.34=0.47\,\Bbb{P}(Y=w\mid X=b)$, so $$\Bbb{P}(Y=w\mid X=b)=\frac{0.34}{0.47}=\frac{34}{47}\approx 0.7234\;.$$

Comment: What I'd like to know is: how do you arrange a jar of marbles so that it produces these probabilities?

Comment: @Brian M. Scott thanks.

Comment: @Robert: Apparently there are $66/19$ marbles in the jar, of which $1551/950$ are black and the remaining $1749/950$ are white!